# Postgres is not using partial index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, explain

I tried to count id in a table using partial index, but performance very low

```
SELECT COUNT("refuel_request"."refuel_request_id") as "count" 
FROM "refuel_request" 
WHERE "refuel_request"."refuel_request_status_id" 
IN ('1','2','3')
```

I am created index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_refuel_request_status_id10 ON refuel_request (refuel_request_status_id)
WHERE "refuel_request"."refuel_request_status_id" 
IN ('1','2','3')
```

Can you explain what do I do wrong?

Explain

```
[
 {
"Plan": {
  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Relation Name": "refuel_request",
  "Alias": "refuel_request",
  "Startup Cost": 0,
  "Total Cost": 160442.88,
  "Plan Rows": 4700100,
  "Plan Width": 16,
  "Filter": "(refuel_request_status_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'))"
   }
  }
 ]
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

[image: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)]

explain (analyze, format text)

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=114931.68..114931.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=570.019..570.020 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=114931.47..114931.68 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=569.735..575.504 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=113931.47..113931.48 rows=1 idth=8) (actual time=528.094..528.094 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on refuel_request cost=0.00..109035.53 rows=1958375 width=16) (actual time=0.070..452.908 rows=1566700 loops=3)
                    Filter: (refuel_request_status_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'))
Planning Time: 0.665 ms
Execution Time: 575.538 ms
```

Comment: Maybe you table is to small - planner choose seq scan in parallel beceuse this method have lover costs to do this query for your table now. Other option is - your clause in cover almost whole table....

Comment: I have 4mln elements in the table

Comment: check same query when index is not partial  - if plan will be without index and if you have only 3 values in condition - maybe query with union all will use non partial index ....

Comment: @areklipno I am tried to use CREATE INDEX idx_refuel_request_status_id ON refuel_request (refuel_request_status_id) . But it is not working

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added text format

Comment: Explain analyze says execution time is half a second, is that too slow?

Comment: @kometen I don`t know why explain analyze said it. Real execution time is one second and it too long for this query

Comment: Is refuel_request_status_id a text-field? Since it is quoted "IN ('1', '2', '3')". Have you tried to change it to "refuel_request_status_id = '1' or ... =  '2' or ... = '3'?

Comment: @kometen nothing changed

Comment: Is refuel_request_status_id a text-field?

Comment: @kometen it is uuid() field

Comment: What is the distribution of refuel_request_status_id? Can you perform a "select count(*) from (select refuel_request_status_id group by refuel_request_status_id);"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No rows are removed by the filter in the sequential scan, so it seems that all rows in the table have `refuel_request_status_id` equal to `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'`. So the `WHERE` condition in the index doesn't make a difference.

You could try with `enable_seqscan = off` to see if PostgreSQL made the right choice. If not, perhaps `random_page_cost` is not correctly set for your hardware.

If it turns out that the sequential scan is indeed the fastest way to go, there is nothing much you can do to speed up the query: you can get faster storage or more RAM to cache the table.

[Counting is slow business.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/)

Comment: enable_seqscan = off  increases execution time to 4 second( 
Do you have any idea for update performance for this query?

Comment: I was wrong about the index-only scan - see my updated answer.